# Геометрическая фигура (параллелограм) на CSS

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Всем привет! 
Возможно, вопрос для многих очень прост, но всё же. Мне надоело использовать картинку, и хочу понемногу расти. Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать такую геометрическую фигуру (она должна быть адаптивной):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И что б контент не изгибался

Comment: если вам помог ответ - отметьте его решением.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это делается с помощью `skew`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 75px;
  height: 25px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: skew(15deg)
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p></p>
  <span>
    Lorem
  </span>
</div>
```

Вариант на `SVG` с тем же `skew`:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
  <rect transform="skewX(15)" width="100" height="50"/>
  <text fill="white" x="35" y="30">Lorem</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: @Air, Спасибо за правку:))

Comment: А сделай еще вариант на svg...

Comment: Пожалуйста.....

Comment: @Air, можно попробовать

Comment: Думаю даже нужно...

Comment: Даже код проще и короче...

Comment: @Air, поэтому `SVG` лучше `CSS` в этом плане:))

Comment: Пошли в чат.....